# GCC Error Infinite While Loop

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int number, total;

int main (void)
{
    total = 0;

    while (true) {
        printf ("Enter a number (-1 to stop)\n");
        scanf (" %d", &number);
        if (number < 0) {
            break;
        }

        total = number + total;
    }

    printf ("The total is %d", total);

    return 0;
}
```

When I use a `while (true)`loop in a C program on OSX, I get the following error

```
'error': use of undeclared identifier 'true' while (true)
```

However when I run this on my Windows partition (through the GCC program), I get no error..

Is this a limitation of GCC on osx?

Comment: Did you `#include` something?

Comment: Yes this is just the snippet from the whole program..

Comment: `true` is not a C keyword. You need to define that yourself or include a header (like `stdbool.h`) which defines that. And even gcc should fail on that code - so please show a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide exact details of your gcc version if you have found otherwise.

Comment: [Here is an example using gcc](https://ideone.com/RaGbGh) which fails to compile as expected. Not sure how you are getting that to compile successfully with gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the top of the file:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

That will define `bool`, `true`, and `false`.